# Concurrent programming and nondeterminism

Tags: concurrency

First , I have to declare , I am not familiar with concurrent / parallel programming, my job is a web(PHP) developer, but I am just interested on such topic.

I am reading "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks" at moment.

On Chapter one, author stated:

> This is unfortunate because concurrent programs are often 
>   nondeterministic — they will give different results depending on the precise timing of events. If you’re working on a **genuinely** concurrent problem, nondeterminism is natural and to be expected.

I do not understand why concurrent programs is non-dererministic in natural?
can any one give me a concrete real live example?

Also , what is "a **genuinely** concurrent problem"?  what is non-genuinely concurrent problem.

By the way, any beginner book for concurrent/parallel book? I am not a math/CS guru, so , please suggest a book with coding examples, not full pages of theories and math formulas.

I can read java/C code

Comment: Non-deterministic "Hello world": Start ten threads, have them all print the numbers from 1 to 100. The exact sequence of numbers in the combined output will be pretty random.  (Okay, Hello World is not concrete real live ...)

Comment: @Thilo, but that not non-deterministic mean right? it is just out of order each time, and each time result just same, it outputs 1-100 integer. it will not outputs 100 eggs for you.

Comment: I was thinking about cooking is a good example about concurrent programing in real live, but cooking result is determined, if you cook a steak, you are not going to get fried fish, which is why i do not understand "non-deterministic"

Comment: oK, may be I am get it now, non-deterministic may be mean , we have a set of pre - derminted results, each time a concurrent program just pickup a result from the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genuinely concurrent problems normally involve interactions with the real world (which is itself made up of all sorts of different things, all happening concurrently, so that shouldn't be surprising).

Here's a real-world example of unavoidable nondeterminism: Imagine that you have $100 in your bank account, and two different companies try to charge your debit card at exactly the same time, one trying to take $90, the other $80.

Depending on the exact details of what happens within your bank's computers, one of these transactions will "win" and the other will be rejected. You might end up with $10 left in your account, or you might end up with $20. Both these outcomes are "correct" but you can't predict in advance which you'll get (and if you do exactly the same thing again, you might get a different result).

Non-genuinely concurrent problems normally result from our attempts to parallelise what *should* be a completely deterministic process (incidentally, this is why it's helpful to understand the difference between concurrency and parallelism). One example from the book is summing all the numbers between 0 and 10000000. The answer should *always* be 49999995000000. But if we use concurrent tools (such as threads and locks) to create a parallel implementation of this problem, and don't get our synchronisation *exactly* right, we might end up with code that (wrongly) behaves non-deterministically.